# Restrict Istio services within the mesh

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

We have an application with several services running in k8s. We want to move them into Istio mesh with mTLS, in which case they all can communicate with each other (until here it is tested). Now, I need to restrict some services **within** the mesh to only be able to talk to one service. Trying to talk to other services that are not authorized, should be blocked. Is this possible?

Since I have no way to configure the "source" of the request, and within the mesh anyone can talk to anyone, I can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't ["Micro-Segmentation with Istio Authorization"](https://istio.io/blog/2018/istio-authorization/) what you are looking for, especially under '[Combinations of Attributes](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/authorization/constraints-and-properties/)' you have different ways of segmentation, based on source.namespace, source.principal. Have seen few demos showcasing these features, not played with them personally though

Comment: I think RBAC in this case would be helpful if I'd want to restrict one service's permissions (say no POST is allowed). But what I need is to restrict all services permissions towards one, and to do it with all other services. This would get complicated exponentially, since I have to start restricting one by one. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've been doing further tests with Istio RBAC, and I think it makes more sense to configure the traffic from outside cluster. It seems to not affect to the requests from services within the mesh.

Comment: Why not follow the approach of Canary deployments as in https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-canary-deployments-for-mere-mortals-13728ce032fe where you could isolate services completely

Comment: not sure how canary release solves the problem. With canary, you are just saying the Pilot to send some requests to another version of the app. What I need it to isolate services within the mesh. Imagine I have an app with 5 services, where 4 services talk to 1 service. Well, then I want these 4 services to not be able to talk to each other. Only to the 5th service. Makes sense?

Comment: @suren jan have you solved your problem? Currently I'm trying to restrict traffic to one service from all services in the mesh except one. Have you used denials for this or another stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Istio 1.1+ includes a new `Sidecar` resource that can be used to configure the envoy sidecar proxy of your services. You should be able to configure egress from your services so that they can only access the one service that they're allowed to call.

[Documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/sidecar/#Sidecar)

Answer (score 0):

Istio can control access to a service based on any attributes that are available within Mixer. So
what you are looking for is [Mixer denier adapter - sample denials](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/denial-and-list/#simple-denials)

e.g.:

"deny all invoke from server1(s1) to server2(s2)"

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: denyotherserverhandler
spec:
  compiledAdapter: denier
  params:
    status:
      code: 7
      message: Not allowed
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: denyotherserverrequest
spec:
  compiledTemplate: checknothing
---
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: denyotherserverrule
spec:
  match: destination.labels["app"] == "s2" && source.labels["app"]=="s1"
  actions:
  - handler: denyotherserverhandler
    instances: [ denyotherserverrequest ]
```